# How to write on same *.shp file after running QGIS 3.0 algorithm?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-processing, qgis-3

I run the `qgis:creategrid` processing tool. When I write output path as `OUTPUT` parameter, it creates the shapefile in given directory. However when I run parameter again after changing some parameters except `OUTPUT` parameter, it does not write on same file with changes.

But I want to write  it on same *.shp file. Here is my code:

```
param = {'TYPE': 2,
         'EXTENT': "329727.56769520865,336312.5556485866,1288173.5555638324,1292085.1509720355",
         'HSPACING': 150,
         'VSPACING': 150,
         'HOVERLAY': 0,
         'VOVERLAY': 0,
         'CRS': "32637",
         'OUTPUT': QgsProcessingOutputLayerDefinition("D:/grid/grid.shp")}

processing.runAndLoadResults("qgis:creategrid", param)
```

For instance when I run it again after changing `HSPACING` parameter, I want to write it on `D:/grid/grid.shp` again.

Answer (score 1):

Actually I could not find the solution of my exact question. However I found a way for my request. If I run the script as `processing.run` instead of `processing.runAndLoadResults`, I can write on file as much as I want. In `OUTPUT` parameter I write shape path `D:/grid/grid.shp`. After that you can add it layer panel by calling defined path.